# Jasmine: how to ignore when no specs found

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Starting with a new project I don't have any tests yet, but I want the build process to succeed.

Is there any "**configuration**" way how to avoid this behaviour without adding any additional code?:

> Incomplete: No specs found
>
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Any parameter for `jasmine.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is thrown by the reporter so you could [clear the reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/Env.html) or else create a very simple spec that will always pass

```
describe('placeholder', () => {

    it('will always pass', async () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Obviously I can do it like this, but this is a very ugly hack. I'm looking for a "configuration" solution...

Comment: I have no knowledge of your experience with Jasmine so would disagree it was obvious at all. Did you try the approach with clearing the reporters? I have only used Jasmine through Protractor but I can suppress the 'no spec found' notification by using that approach.

Comment: Unfortunately both solutions need an additional code to be written. This is what I wanted to avoid. But you're right: It was not so clear from the question, so I edited it slightly. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Ah I get your requirement now. Unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to assist further but hope you find an answer